# SQL foreign constraints

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to to keys from different tables, and when I succeed, I get this error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.

This is how my database looks like:

```
 POST           COMMENTS

 id             id 

 post           comment

 ---------      post_id
```

I want to `connect POST id to COMMENTS post_id.` When I try to add a comment on my site, that error message shows up, or sometimes in phpmyadmin whem I'm trying to make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read your question after you've written it? Do you honestly think it's possible to get what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I bet you created the Foreign Key constraint the other way around :).

In your case post_id from the Comments table is the Foreign Key that references the Id in the Post table.

Otherwise it should work as long as you make sure you have an entry in POST first. You cannot add a row in COMMENTS if you do not link it to a row in POST!